# vim mapping K to external command

Tags: vim

I'd like to map vim's `'keywordprg'` to [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash), namely, use `K` to do `!open dash://word-unser-curse`.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
:let &keywordprg '!open dash://'
```

but it says `E34: No previous command`.

Answer (score 0):

from `:h E34`:

```
        Any '!' in {cmd} is replaced with the previous
        external command (see also 'cpoptions').  But not when
        there is a backslash before the '!', then that
        backslash is removed.  Example: ":!ls" followed by
        ":!echo ! \! \\!" executes "echo ls ! \!".
```

Thus you have to escape `!` in order to have vim treat as it is, otherwise vim tries to replace it with the "previous command", resulting in the error.

Additionally, I don't think you need that `!` in your `keywordprg`. Vim calls it as an external command anyway (the default value is `man`, not `!man`).